# Instantiate ViewModel with composable scope

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, navigation-compose

I want to instantiate a ViewModel with scope of a Composable function.

How can I do this?

I don't want to use `navigation-compose` to take advantage of its `BackStackEntry` as ViewModelStoreOwner.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue recently, the only I could solve it by instantiating it manually using remember, not that perfect but it solved my use case for now.

To do the same, you can do something like:

```
val composeScopeViewModel = remember {
    ResidentDetailsViewModel(
        // params if any
    )
}
```